# Swagger UI redirecting to /swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am using `springdoc-openapi-ui`, when I hit http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html URL it is always redirecting to http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config. Is there any way to stop this redirect and load swagger on http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have asked the same question on `Github` site regarding the same. Link is provided below
https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/742#issue-642810354
Got the reply from one of the contributor

`springdoc-openapi uses an internal redirect to resolve the necessary swagger resources. This the way the library is built.`
`You use you own version of swagger-ui, so you can add your custom Logic, without having to rely on springdoc-openapi-ui.`

Comment: how to add this custom logic, example please? autoconfigure does not provide "springfox.documentation.swagger-ui.config-url" proprerty. inspecting UiConfiguration also can't find suitable props.

Answer (score 3):

this is not about the redirect, as it works to just open to http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html. But some answers are about disabling the petshop and configUrl. Supplying configUrl is not working anymore for a autoconfigured springdoc. Overwriting the url, config-url (if needed) and default url works with the following application.yml:

```yaml
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    url: "/v3/api-docs"
    disable-swagger-default-url: true
```

or you can use the topics plugin:

```yaml
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    disable-swagger-default-url: true
    urls:
      - url: "/v3/api-docs"
        name: "myService"
```

Comment: these two properties are what you need! url and disable-swagger-default-url. worked for me! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this issue because our app is behind a gateway/load balancer and on Docker. My goal is to really just access the Swagger UI and my workaround is to access `/swagger-ui/index.html` directly. It loads the "Swagger Petstore". In the "Explore" field, I type `/v3/api-docs` to load my application's APIs.

Comment: Did you find a way to make `/v3/api-docs` default url?

Comment: Haven't found a way yet. Someone suggested using `springdoc.swagger-ui.disable-swagger-default-url=true` to disable the "Swagger Petstore" page. But I still need to access `/swagger-ui/index.html` then search for `/v3/api-docs`.

Answer (score -2):

I found a post to workaround for this. Scan and modify the index.html to replace petStore URL for apiDoc URL

```
    @Configuration

    public class DocOpenApiConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**/*.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/")
                .resourceChain(false)
                .addResolver(new WebJarsResourceResolver())
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver())
                .addTransformer(new IndexPageTransformer());
    }

    public static class IndexPageTransformer implements ResourceTransformer {

        private String overwriteDefaultUrl(String html) {
            return html.replace("https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json",
                    "/v3/api-docs");
        }

        @Override
        public Resource transform(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, Resource resource, ResourceTransformerChain resourceTransformerChain) throws IOException {
            if (resource.getURL().toString().endsWith("/index.html")) {
                String html = IOUtils.toString(resource.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                html = overwriteDefaultUrl(html);
                return new TransformedResource(resource, html.getBytes());
            } else {
                return resource;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach uses the interceptor to replace all the request coming for /index.html to convertion as per your overwriteDefaultUrl(html). But this is not clean as unwanted response comes when you load other "/index.html" files